# If $\mathbb E [ |X-Y|^2 ] < +\infty$ then both $X$ and $Y$ have finite second-moments

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, expected-value, independence

I'm trying to verify below result, i.e.,

> Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P)$ be a probability space and $X,Y:\Omega \to \mathbb R$ independent random variables. If $\mathbb E [ |X-Y|^2 ] < +\infty$ then both $X$ and $Y$ have finite second-moments.

Could you have a check on my below attempt?

---

**Proof** We define the map $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R \cup \{+\infty\}$ by
$$
f(x) := \mathbb E [ |x-Y|^2 ].
$$

Then $f$ is Borel measurable. Because $X$ and $Y$ are independent,
$$
\mathbb E[f(X)] = \mathbb E [ |X-Y|^2 ].
$$

If $\mathbb E [ |Y|^2] = +\infty$ then $f(x) = +\infty$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$ and thus $\mathbb E[f(X)] = +\infty$, which is a contradiction. This completes the proof.

Comment: How does $\mathbb E[|X|^2] = +\infty$ imply $f(x) = +\infty$?

Comment: @RobertIsrael Ah it's a typo. I meant $\mathbb E [ |Y|^2] = +\infty$ implies $f(x) = +\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are trying to do the following. Because $X$ and $Y$ are independent,
$$
\mathbf{E}(f(X,Y) \mid X = x ) = \mathbf{E}(f(x,Y)),
$$
therefore
$$
\mathbf{E}(f(X,Y)) = \mathbf{E}(\mathbf{E}(f(X,Y) \mid X)) = \int dF_X(x) \mathbf{E}(f(x,Y)).
$$
The exercise uses $f(u,v) = |u - v|^2,$ and the hypothesis implies at once that $\mathbf{E}(f(x,Y)) < \infty$ for almost every $x$ according to $F_X.$ One can conclude then that there exists $x$ such that $\mathbf{E}(f(x,Y)) < \infty.$ *Thus, you should prove the following:*

**Claim:** A necessary and sufficient condition for $Y$ to have second moment is that there exists $a \in \mathbf{R}$ such that $a - Y$ also have second moment. In other words, $\mathbf{E}(Y^2) < \infty$ if and only if there is *some* $a \in \mathbf{R}$ such that $\mathbf{E}(|a - Y|^2) < \infty.$

(My point being is that you are in the right track, except you haven't justified a few steps and your quantifiers are not quite right either.)

Comment: Could you elaborate on which of my quantifiers are not right?

Comment: At the end, you conclude that if $E(Y^2) = \infty,$ then so $f(x) = \infty$ for all $x.$ The argument using tower property first shows that $E(|x - Y|^2)$ is finite for some $x,$ then you should prove this implies $E(Y^2) < \infty.$

Comment: I could not see how my statement *"If $\mathbb E [ |Y|^2] = +\infty$ then $f(x) = +\infty$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$"* is wrong. My argument is as follows. Assume the contrary that there is some $x_0 \in \mathbb R$ such that $f(x_0) = \mathbb E [ |x_0-Y|^2 ]  < \infty$. Then  $\mathbb E [ |Y|^2 ] \le 2\mathbb E [ |x_0-Y|^2 ] + 2x_0^2 < \infty$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: I misread you, you didn't conclude anything but rather gave a proof by contradiction. (And by the way, I never said the statement was wrong.)